# How to read PHP output row by row and create HTML-links from each row

Tags: pdf, php, html

I'm having this PHP-script:

```
<?php

   $old_path = getcwd();
   chdir('/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/');
   $term1 = $_POST['query1'];
   $term2 = $_POST['query2'];
   $var = "{$term1} {$term2}";
   $outcome = shell_exec("searcher $var");
   chdir($old_path);
   echo "<pre>$outcome</pre>";
?>
```

On a searchpage two searchwords are written and the searchbutton is pushed. The search result turns up as a webpage like this:

```
/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf:1
/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf:3
/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf:7
/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf:7
/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf:9
/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf:13
/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf:13
```

The result shows links to individual PDF-files and pagenumber in that file, but are not clickable.

Is there a way to make these links clickable so that it opens up for instance in Evince or Acrobat at the correct page number?

Many thanks in advance.

/Paul

Comment: Yes.  Add the a tag to the html and embed each strip g into the href and as the value. Or add the actual a tag (html)  to the php code

Comment: quick hint though: `<pre>$outcome</pre>` might be edited to emit a properly formatted link tag instead of a pre tag. Note that those paths are internal to the server and may not be reachable from the client.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but without success. It seems as $outcome contains a number of rows. I guess all these rows must be either put in an array and the read OR possibly read directly from $outcome in a for- or while-loop. I just don't know how to construct it properly. An Dave, I don't reallt understand what you mean by "embed each strip g into the href"?

Answer (score 0):

I found a correct answer to my problem. It took some time, but here it is:

```
<?php

// Get current working directory and put it as variable
   $old_path = getcwd();
// Change directory 
   chdir('/var/www/html/SEARCHTOOLS/');
// Create first variable as result of first searchword on searchpage
   $term1 = $_POST['query1'];
// Create second variable as result of second searchword on searchpage
   $term2 = $_POST['query2'];
// Create a variable combining first AND second variable
   $var = "{$term1} {$term2}";
// Create a variable as the result of the executed search using command "sokare" and variable "$var"
   $outcome = shell_exec("sokare $var");
// Return to starting directory
   chdir($old_path);
// Split the varible "$outcome" per line representing every page in PDF-file where variable "$var" is found
   foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $outcome) as $line){
// Create a variable out of the given pagenumber in PDF-file
   $end = substr($line, strpos($line, ":") + 1);
// Trim the line by removing leading directories from line    
   $line2 = str_replace('/var/www/html', '', $line);
// Change a string from lower to upper case
   $line2 = str_replace('searchtools', 'SEARCHTOOLS', $line2);
// Remove the colon and anything behind it from line
   $line2 = array_shift(explode(':', $line2));
// Add suffix to line to facilitate linking to pagenumber in PDF-file
   $line3 = str_replace(" ", "_", $line2).'#page=';
// Add pagenumber from the variable "$end"
   $line3 = str_replace(" ", "_", $line3).$end;
// Print each line as a correct URL-link
   echo "<pre><a href=$line3>$line3</a></pre>";
}
?>
```

The search results will now turn up as (and are clickable):

```
/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf#page=1
/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf#page=3
/SEARCHTOOLS/1974-1991.pdf#page=7
```

Just a small edit. The line ....

```
// Add suffix to line to facilitate linking to pagenumber in PDF-file
       $line3 = str_replace(" ", "_", $line2).'#page=';
```

...works better with:

```
// Add suffix to line to facilitate linking to pagenumber in PDF-file
   if (substr($line2, -3) == 'pdf') {
   $line3 = $line2.'#page=';
```

}